# add a dynamic created element in div editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a dynamic created element (`<a>`) in a div editable without deleting its content.

When I insert the element with no content into the editable div, it works but that's not what I want.

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode('Test');
link.appendChild(linkText);
link.setAttribute('data-id', 1);
link.setAttribute('data-type', 12);
  link.href  = 'wwww.google.com';
  // this is ok 
  $('#editable').html(link);
 // but when inserting the old html  is not ok 
$('#editable').html($('#editable').html() + link);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" required="required" name="editable" id="editable" data-editable="true" contenteditable="true">Add request ...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `append`

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode('Test');
link.appendChild(linkText);
link.setAttribute('data-id', 1);
link.setAttribute('data-type', 12);
link.href = 'wwww.google.com';
$('#editable').append(link);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" required="required" name="editable" id="editable" data-editable="true" contenteditable="true">Add request ...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not completely in jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('<a/>')
    .attr({
      'data-id': 1,
      'data-type': 12,
      'href': 'http://www.google.com' })
    .text('Test')
    .appendTo( $('#editable') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="message" required="required" name="editable" id="editable" data-editable="true" contenteditable="true">Add request ...</div>
```